# How to handle default data in an application using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm working on an application that uses SQL Server and NHibernate.  We have the concept of default data (complex entities) that needs to be created for each new entity.  This data can be changed on a per-user basis.  However, we're struggling with the best way to create this data.

For example, lets say my application has a `Store` entity which has several default `Product`s that I want to create when a new `Store` gets created. Anything about a`Product` can be modified by managers of each `Store`.

As I see it, there are two main options:

1. Keep the default data in code and write it to the database once the new entity is created.
2. Keep the default data in the database and move it over with a stored procedure/raw SQL when the entity is created.

Instinctively, I lean toward option two, since databases are great at moving and manipulating sets of data, and option one would require a ton of messy code that could get out of hand.

However, writing a stored procedure or raw SQL presents its own issues:

- We would have to re-write the stored procedure or SQL depending on the database we're using
- We would be subverting the ORM in a way (not sure if this is actually wrong).  That is, we'd be moving data around without using NHibernate

I found [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/2006/04/18/BulkDataOperationsUsingNHibernate.aspx) article by Ayende Rahien which outlines how to perform a bulk delete.  I am thinking that doing something similar for inserting default data would be fine.  I also found an nhibernate users groups post (called "Schema export and default data"--SO won't let me post two links) that describes a similar situation, but it doesn't seem like there's a consensus on what the right solution is (although Ayende does offer some feedback and suggests that the data live in the database).

After writing this, I'm leaning even more toward using a stored procedure, I'm just worried about possible pitfalls of mixing two database access strategies (directly calling SProcs and using an ORM).

Any feedback is appreciated!

**Edit:** Removed "immutable" language.  I'm specifically talking about default data that can change so I think this term was incorrect/confusing here.

Comment: Can you clarify; are you actually mapping these objects as immutable? If so, see this (somewhat hacky) article regarding how this can be subverted, may be applicable in your scenario: http://jameskovacs.com/2007/11/04/testing-immutable-entities-with-nhibernate/   In either case, could you post your mappings? that would be helpful I think...

Comment: I updated the original post--I mean more 'default' data that originally is the same for all entities but then can change on a per-entity basis.

Comment: In that case...have a look at: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/05/nhibernate-210-executable-queries.html - it is possible to do inserts and updates using hql alone...

Comment: @DanP: That link is very helpful, but it looks like the examples use bulk inserts from a table containing one type of NH entity to another. I don't necessarily see default data as a domain concern (not always at least) and so I would be hesitant to create separate 'default' NH entities and 'editable' NH entities.  Maybe this is the way to go though.

Comment: @Andrew: I believe you can insert values from params as well (rather than selecting from some other mapped table); couldn't you just specify your default data to be inserted somewhere in your infrastructure layer. I *thought* your goal was to keep it database-independant, which the executable hql would achieve.

Comment: @DanP: That seems like a good idea; we could keep pure data in the infrastructure layer and use HQL to insert it, making the code much simpler than having to deal with creating new entities and pushing them to the database. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do...you may even be able to wrap it all in a named query to simlify the operation. By the way, be sure to answer this question; I'm curious (and I'm sure others will be) how you solved this...

Comment: Another thought...you probably could use a mapped class for the default data...no one says that all of your models *need* to reside in the domain layer; you could have the default data models in the infrastructure layer...that's another option as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a default data service that creates those data in code, and use a factory to create your store and use the default data service to generate the default entities.
Using a Stored Procedure definitely defeats the point of having an ORM.